# Can a Flameskull's spells be Counterspelled?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, monsters, counterspelling

Counterspell requires the following:

> [a reaction], which you take when you see a creature within 60 feet of you casting a spell

The Flameskull's spellcasting block reads the following:

> [The Flameskull] requires no somatic or material components to cast its spells.

If the Flameskull requires no visible components, can its spells be counterspelled?

Comment: I actually don't think this is a duplicate. This question is asking about counterspelling a spell with no material or somatic components, but verbal components are still included. The duplicate is about Subtle spell (No verbal or somatic needed) plus no material components. There's a...subtle difference because this question includes spells with verbal components.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### If you see the creature and perceive its spellcasting, you can counter it

Just because the spell has no visible components doesn't mean you can't see a creature casting it. Because the flameskull's spells still require verbal components, you know when it is casting a spell as long as you can hear it. If you see a creature and you know it is casting a spell, then you see it casting a spell, which satisfies the requirement for casting *Counterspell*.

### You can only counter a spell if you perceive at least one of its components

If you were deafened, or if there was an area of silence or some other reason that you couldn't hear the verbal components of the flameskull's spellcasting, or if the flameskull casts a spell with no verbal component<sup>1</sup>, then you would be unable to perceive any components of the spell, and therefore you would not know the spell was being cast until after it took effect and it was too late to counter it.

---

<sup>1</sup>not possible without homebrew, since all the standard flameskull's spells have  verbal component

Comment: I feel it would be good to add that all of the spells a Flameskull can cast have the verbal component, so all of their spells can be perceived.